# How efficient is Windows 8 in using battery power as compared to Windows 7 in similar power plans?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, battery, energy-saving

I'm very specific about the time my laptop battery can last as it is very important to me. Will my laptop's battery last longer with Windows 8 or Windows 7, both in similar power plans, considering factors such that Aero is disabled in Windows 8 and many others?

Comment: There is a slight improvement just as microsoft says. You might end up with 10 minutes of extra juice or half an hour , a lot depends on the condition of your battery too. Your battery was younger when running windows 7 ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been some comparison in the battery life between Windows 8 and Windows 7. Very early tests in the preview showed no improvement, but the latest benchmarks appear to show slight improvement.

[image]

You should be aware that battery life will depend on your actual hardware, drivers used, and settings (screen brightness, etc).

The programs installed will also be a factor, for example, the following shows how it can change:

[image]

*Note: the above comparisons are based on specific hardware, and the setup used for the tests may differ from yours*

Sources:

- http://www.tomsguide.com/us/win8-speed-performance,review-1760-3.html
- http://www.windows7port.com/1217/windows-7-vs-windows-8-battery-life/
- http://blog.tune-up.com/news/windows-8-stress-test-how-3rd-party-programs-ruin-the-new-oss-performance-2/

Comment: I think we'll see some improvements when the next generation of chipsets/CPUs come out that Windows 8 will be able to make us off and Windows 7 can't.